# What is the correct way to read chapter numbers? (e.g.: 第1話)

Tags: kanji, readings, counters

I see this form often in manga book indexes. My dictonary gives me ダイ and テイ as possible readings for the first kanji, and I'm also not sure if the number should be read as a counter (like 一つ is read ひとつ and not いちつ). How should I read those?

Comment: てい is a _very_ rare reading of the character 第 (I wasn't even aware of it before now). The only word I was able to find that uses it was [第宅【ていたく】](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=1436820), and 第 isn't even the kanji most commonly used in that word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ordinal prefix 第 is read だい.  This is [sense two in 大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/132400/m0u/%E7%AC%AC/):

> ［接頭］数を表す語に付いて、ものの順序を表すのに用いる。「世界―一の都会」「―五巻」「―三レース」「―六感」

The counter 話 is read わ, and [it attaches to Sino-Japanese numerals such as いち](http://www.trussel.com/jcount.htm).

Put it all together and you get だいいちわ.

Comment: いち vs. いっ.  第１話 is read だいいちわ, but 第１巻(Volume 1) is read だいいっかん..